# Search Whitespaces in URLs and Replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I don't quite understand how regexes work. I have an xml file that I need to search and replace specific white spaces in it.

Example:

I have part of a URL that looks like this:

```
/l-San Francisco CA
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
/l-San+Francisco+CA
```

I have thousands of URLs in the XML file that I need to fix. Manually going through and searching and replacing each one in Notepad++ is extremely tedious.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle the option 'grep search' on in the np++ find options.  Then search for

```
\/(.*) (.*)$
```

But you might not need to escape the initial forward-slash:

```
/(.*) (.*)$
```

And replace it with:

```
/\1+\2
```

You might need to do replace all a few times to fix the new matches that the previous replace created, but 4 clicks is better then 4000 :).

*Always a good idea to double check that the regex works on a single match before 'replace all'.*

---

Or replace:

```
/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)$
```

With:

```
/\1+\2
```

Comment: You can install the `RegEx Helper` plugin to highlight all matches, scroll through the file, and make sure your final product isn't messed up. You can also use the `Compare` plugin to visually compare the diffs of the two different versions.

Comment: The first code above adds +'s to the anchor text words: /l-San Francisco CA">San Francisco CA</a> becomes /l-San Francisco CA">San Francisco+CA</a>  Second code didn't work at all.

Comment: I figured it out.  search \l-(.*) (.*)CA" replace l-\1+\2CA"  Run that twice on every state and good to go.  Thanks for the help.